# typo3 how to add a second backend Module

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

in my typo3 extension I want to add a second backend modul in navigation.

in `ext_tables.php` I have this:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

    /**
     * Creates a Backend Module Category
     */

    $modulName = 'InstitutsShop';
    //Legt die Position des Moduls fest, hier nach Modul "web"
    if (!isset($TBE_MODULES[$modulName])) {
        $temp_TBE_MODULES = array();
        foreach ($TBE_MODULES as $key => $val) {
            if ($key == 'web') {
                $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
                $temp_TBE_MODULES[$modulName] = '';
            } else {
                $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        $TBE_MODULES = $temp_TBE_MODULES;
    }

    // Hauptmodul erstellen
    t3lib_extMgm::addModule($modulName, '', '', t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Configuration/BackendModule/');

    /**
     * Registers a Backend Module
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,    // $extensionName  =>   vendor + extkey, seperated by a dot
        'InstitutsShop',          // $mainModuleName =>   Make module a submodule of 'Auditgarant'
        'shopbackend',          // $subModuleName  =>   module name
        '',                     // $position       =>   position in the group
        array(                  // Allowed controller -> action combinations
            'ShopBackend' => 'list, showOrder',
        ),
        array(                  // $moduleConfiguratione
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon' => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/ext_icon_small.svg',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_shop_backend.xlf',
        )
    );

    /**
     * Registers a Backend Module
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,    // $extensionName  =>   vendor + extkey, seperated by a dot
        'InstitutsShop Produkte',          // $mainModuleName =>   Make module a submodule of 'Auditgarant'
        'shopbackendproducts',          // $subModuleName  =>   module name
        '',                     // $position       =>   position in the group
        array(                  // Allowed controller -> action combinations
            'ShopOrdProduct' => 'list',
        ),
        array(                  // $moduleConfiguratione
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon' => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/ext_icon_small.svg',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_shop_backend.xlf',
        )
    );
}
```

The first one with controller `ShopBackend` is displayed ... 
The second one not.

What could be the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add a few actions inside one module and display them with a simple menu

Comment: I would add a few actions inside one module and display them with a simple menu

Comment: In which typo3 version you wanna add backend module? Is your extension based on Extbase or PI?

Comment: typo3 6.2.31 
extbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the space is not allowed in the mainModuleName. And I don't think that your extension has the vendor `TYPO3`.